# Tikz picture, align left in column using beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, horizontal-alignment

I'm currently struggling with aligning a `tikzpicture`, within a figure environment, at the left of a column. It seems like the figure is always align centre, or right

Using beamer, for a presentation.

```
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \input{pics/tikzpicture.tex}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
```

Comment: why do you need the figure environment there at all?

Comment: Please add a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question that should at least contain the concerned frame. At the moment it is quite difficult to visualize what you want do.

Answer (score 5):

The figure environment appears to be serving no purpose in your example, so you could simply delete it, however you can use `\flushleft` to override the default centering in figure if you need to.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
XXX

\begin{figure}
YYY
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\flushleft
ZZZ
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
XXX
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did try flushleft but did not work out, is that because I wrapped the figure environment (ie figure was laid inside.)

Comment: @Jesse figure in beamer is more or less just the same as `center` it doesn't float, it just centers its contents so adding figure and flushleft works but is essentially a no-op

Answer (score 1):

This is my trial:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[l]
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\hspace{-3cm}\includegraphics[width=1cm]{flag_usa}\hfill
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Wihtout `\hspace{-xxcm}`, it won't work even `\hfill` is added. Oh, I forget to say that this works for `tikzpicture` environment too.